# Is there a way to have a script reference an object as a field?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

I've had trouble searching around and may be critically misunderstanding how Unity wants you to structure your project, but here is my situation:

I have characters in my game and would like to configure them in the editor. I have made classes that represent different behavior types and actions that can be performed. **Is there a way for me to make a field on a script typed for these classes so that I can drag and drop using the inspector to configure different prefabs?**

Here is some code demonstrating the situation:

Unit.cs

```cs
// A unit on the board.
public class Unit : MonoBehaviour
{
    public UnitAction action;
}
```

UnitAction.cs

```cs
// A unit on the board.
public class UnitAction : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Does things
}
```

These fields show up in the inspector once this script is applied to a prefab, but there are no options to populate the default field value. If I make the field type `UnityEngine.Object`, I can put the scripts there, but that seems like something I do not want.

Comment: So what is the question? You need to have the right types for your public fields, so for example if you want to add a GameObject prefab, declare it as `public GameObject go` or  a transform/script or what ever you need.

Comment: The problem I have is that I have these fields on the class and it shows up in the inspector, but I cannot apply any UnitBehavior or UnitAction scripts to the field. It does not allow me to drag them over from Assets and when I click to browse there is nothing in the list. I can apply this scripts at the same level as my Unit script on a prefab, but not as a field on the Unit script. Do I need to have these scripts attached to something before I can apply them to the field? Both UnitBehavior and UnitAction inherit from MonoBehavior in this case.

Comment: @TylerHackbarth Do you want to have default fields on the scripts in editor? To actually fill these fields they must be on an object either in scene or as a prefab.

Comment: @TEEBQNE Yes, that is exactly it. I want to use the editor to configure different units with different sets of actions or whatever. Thank you! Is there overhead associated with potentially having many game objects for this purpose? My gut feeling is to do configuration in the Unity editor, not code, but I do not know the "Unity way" to do this.

Comment: You would reference **instances** of such a "script" .. **not** the Script file itself ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to serialize references to scripts themselves instead of instances of those scripts. There are a couple of ways that you may want to do this:

1. You could attach your UnitAction scripts as components of a GameObject that is in a context accessible to your "Unit" object (in the same scene, a child of the "Unit" object, or - probably the most common case - the "Unit" object itself). Then you will be able to serialize those instantiated components into the fields in your Unit class. This is the most common use case.
2. You could create a prefab for each of your UnitAction components and then serialize those prefabs into your Unit class fields. You would then instantiate a UnitAction at runtime. This doesn't really seem appropriate for your case based on what you described because a UnitAction probably isn't something that needs to be dynamically instantiated, but it is important to be aware of. This article has an example of using this method for giving a unit a list of spells (and also provides some good context on how to think about using unity components that would probably be valuable to you):

[Unity: Now You're Thinking With Components](https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/articles/unity-now-youre-thinking-with-components--gamedev-12492)

Answer (score 2):

I would guess and say you do not want these scripts exposed except in editor, so you can use an attribute called [`SerializeField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html). It will expose the field to the editor so you are able to drag in references, but other scripts will not be able to access the fields you drop in.

If you want a specific script to appear in the editor, simply write

```
[SerializeField] private YourScriptName scriptReference = null;
```

As lists are generic structures, if you want, you can also make a list of scripts in a similar way

```
[SerializeField] private List<YourScriptName> scriptListReference = new List<YourScriptName>();
```

As I do not think you will be assigning these references again, if you want to grab the reference at any point, you can make a getter method.

```
public YourScriptName GetYourScript(){ return scriptReference;}
```

There are very few fields that Unity can not serialize, so generally, if you want to drag in a reference to a component, script, object, etc. all you need to do is make it either `SerializeField` or public followed by the type of whatever you want to drag in.

From the docs, the serialization system

> CANNOT serialize static fields.
>
> CANNOT serialize properties.
>
> CAN serialize public non-static fields (of serializable types)
>
> CAN serialize nonpublic non-static fields marked with the SerializeField attribute.

The fields that it can serialize are as follows

- All classes inheriting from UnityEngine.Object, for example
  GameObject, Component, MonoBehaviour, Texture2D, AnimationClip.
- All basic data types, such as int, string, float, bool.
- Some built-in types, such as Vector2, Vector3, Vector4, Quaternion, Matrix4x4, Color, Rect, LayerMask.
- Arrays of a serializable type Lists of a
  serializable type
- Enums
- Structs